# python canvas create image in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-chess

Hello i recently started studying tkinter and decided to pick up chess board game.
Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="white", color2="blue"):
        '''size is the size of a square, in pixels'''

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = columns * size
        canvas_height = rows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="bisque")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

root = tk.Tk()
board = GameBoard(root)
board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)

black_rook_l = tk.PhotoImage(file=black_rook_img)
black_rook_l = black_rook_l.subsample(2, 2)
board.addpiece("black_rook_l", black_rook_l, 0,0)
```

above code i is to add piece (black rook) to the board, which is working as expected.

below is the helper functions:

```
def addpiece(self, name, image, row=0, column=0):
    '''Add a piece to the playing board'''
    self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image, tags=(name, "piece"), anchor="c")
    self.placepiece(name, row, column)

def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
    '''Place a piece at the given row/column'''
    self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
    x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
    y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
    # print(name, x0, y0)
    self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)
```

But problem occurs when i try to place pawns with help of for loop.
Below is the code:

```
for i in range(8):
    bname = tk.PhotoImage(file=black_pawn_img)
    bname = bname.subsample(2, 2)
    board.addpiece("black_pawn_"+str(i), bname, 1,i)

root.mainloop()
```

it is placing only last Pawn piece.

Please suggest/help me understand the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the error you get?

Comment: @MosheSlavin , I am not getting any error.
it's just all pawns should be placed but only last pawn is placed/visible.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  The code you posted won't run because it requires a `GameBoard` class.

Comment: @BryanOakley , I have GameBoard class also in my code but I think it is not related to my problem, so I didn't post that.
<br>Apologies for that.<br>
Updated the code for class<br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python image objects are getting destroyed by the garbage collector. You need to save references to the images. The first time through the loop, `bname` holds a reference to the first image that is created. In the next iteration, `bname` is modified to refer to the second image. Because of that, the first image no longer has a reference.

A simple way would be to keep track of them in the block of code that creates them:

```
images = []
for i in range(8):
    bname = tk.PhotoImage(file=black_pawn_img)
    bname = bname.subsample(2, 2)
    board.addpiece("black_pawn_"+str(i), bname, 1,i)
    images.append(bname)
```

Another way would be to have `addpiece` save them:

```
class GameBoard(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.images = []
        ...
    def addpiece(self, name, image, row=0, column=0):
        ...
        self.images.append(image)
        ...
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. <br>It worked but I was wondering that why in for loop, image objects are getting destroyed by the garbage collector and not other image objects. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Aj06: they are getting destroyed because you aren't keeping a reference. `bname` points to an image at the start of the loop, then in the next iteration it's reset to a new image. The previous image no longer has a reference.